# Nationality in a symfony form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1

**I am trying to create a nationality from field using Symfony2.1:**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder->add('nationality','country');
}
```

I managed to display the country:

```
{{user.nationality | country  }}
```

The "value" for each country is the two-letter country code.

**Is there a way to display the nationality from the 2-letter country code instead?**

I don't think there is a twig filter for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a Twig filter that does something like this:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Locale\Locale;

return Locale::getDisplayCountries($locale)[$countryCode];
```